# incorrect output when using C++ lower/upper_bound function with custom compare operator

Tags: c++, stl, upperbound

I've been experimenting with the "lower_bound()/upper_bound()" functions in C++ w.r.t. arrays/vectors, and I get incorrect results when applying custom compare operators to the function.
My current understanding (based on https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/upper_bound/) is that when you search for some value 'val' (of any datatype) in an array, it returns the first iterator position "it" in the array (from left to right) that satisfies **!comp(val,*it)**, is this wrong? If so, how exactly does the searching work?

P.S. In addition, what is the difference of using lowerbound/upperbound when your searching criterion is a specific boolean compare function?

---

Here is an example that produced erroneous results:

```
auto comp2 = [&](int num, pair<int,int>& p2){return num>p2.second;};
vector<pair<int,int>> pairs = {{1,2},{2,3},{3,4}};   //this array should be binary-searchable with 'comp2' comparator, since pairs[i].second is monotonously increasing
int pos2 = upper_bound(pairs.begin(),pairs.end(),2,comp2)-pairs.begin();               
cout<<pos2<<endl;                                   //outputs 3, but should give 0 because !comp2(2,arr[0]) is true, and arr[0] is the ealiest element in the array
```

Thanks!

Comment: There are no elements in `pairs` for which the predicate is `true`.

Comment: So how is the custome compare function used in upperbound function? Should it return the position of the first element where predicate is true or false?

Answer (score 1):

I think most (If not all) of the comparator functions are `less`, it can be `std::less` or something similar. So when we provide a custom `comp` function, we have to provide the `less` logic and think of it as `less`.

Now back to the `upper_bound`, it returns the first element greater than the `value`, which means our `less` should return `true` for it to stop (As Francois pointed out). While our comp function always returns `false`.

And your understanding about `!comp(val,*it)` is also not correct. It is the condition to continue the search, not to stop it.

Here is an [example implementation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/upper_bound) of the `upper_bound`, let's take a look:

```
template<class ForwardIt, class T, class Compare>
ForwardIt upper_bound(ForwardIt first, ForwardIt last, const T& value, Compare comp)
{
    ForwardIt it;
    typename std::iterator_traits<ForwardIt>::difference_type count, step;
    count = std::distance(first, last);
 
    while (count > 0) {
        it = first; 
        step = count / 2;
        std::advance(it, step);
        if (!comp(value, *it)) {
            first = ++it;
            count -= step + 1;
        } 
        else
            count = step;
    }
    return first;
}
```

You can see, `if (!comp(value, *it))` is when the `less` return `false`, it means the `value` is greater than the current item, it will move forward and continue from the next item. (Because the items are increasing).

In the other case, it will try to reduce the search distance (By half the `count`) and hope to find earlier item that is greater than `value`.

Summary: You have to provide `comp` as `less` logic and let the `upper_bound` do the rest.

Answer (score 0):

`upper_bound` returns the first element that satisfies `comp(val, *it)`. In the [link](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/upper_bound/) you provided, it shows

```
template <class ForwardIterator, class T>
  ForwardIterator upper_bound (ForwardIterator first, ForwardIterator last, const T& val)
{
    ForwardIterator it;
    iterator_traits<ForwardIterator>::difference_type count, step;
    count = std::distance(first,last);
    while (count>0)
    {
        it = first; step=count/2; std::advance (it,step);
        if (!(val<*it))                 // or: if (!comp(val,*it)), for version (2)
          { first=++it; count-=step+1;  }
        else count=step;
    }
    return first;
}
```

> Returns an iterator pointing to the first element in the range [first,last) which compares greater than val.

The searching works by starting at position 0(`first`). It then uses `count` to see the range of values it needs to check. It checks the middle of the range (`first+count/2`), and if that does not satisfy the condition, that position is now `first` (discarding all values before it), and repeats with the new first and range. If it does satisfy the condition, then the algorithm can discard all values after that, and repeat with the new range. When the range drops to 0, the algorithm can end. It assumes that if `arr[5]` is false, `arr[0], arr[1] ... arr[4]` are also false. Same with if `arr[8]` is true, `arr[9], arr[10] ... arr[n]` are also true.

The reason your code does not work is because the comparator used returns `num>p2.second`, meaning it looks for a value of `p2.second` that is less than `num`. Since you put in `2` for `num`, and there is no `p2.second` less than that in the vector, the output points to a position outside of the vector because it didn't find anything.

The difference between `upper_bound` and `lower_bound` is that `upper_bound` looks for the first value that satisfies the condition, while `lower_bound` looks for the first value that *does not* satisfy the condition. So

```
lower_bound(v.begin(), v.end(), val, [](int it, int val) {return !(val < it);});
```

is the same as

```
upper_bound(v.begin(), v.end(), val, [](int val, int it){return val < it;});
```

Note that for `lower_bound`, the comparator used takes `(*it, val)`, not `(val, *it)`.

I guess the only difference is how easy it is to frame the comparator in those terms - realizing that `a<b` is the same as `not a>=b`.

More explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41958581/difference-between-upper-bound-and-lower-bound-in-stl). I liked the explanation that said it finds `[lower_bound, upper_bound)` when using the same comparator.

Comment: Hi Kenntnisse, sorry for the late reply, but your response really helped. It had nothing to do with the "less" logic mentioned by other people, since the concept of less can be defined anyhow. Turns out I was using upper_bound() in the way that I should be using lower_bound(). Many thanks.